# Aliens farmed for secretions, young man given power to communicate with them

Tags: story-identification, aliens, communication

I'm looking for the title and author of a science fiction book that I read about ten years ago.

It involved people on an alien world where a local insect species are farmed (rather haphazardly) for their secretions. One young man tasked with attempting communicating with the alien species is injured and unexpectedly nursed back to life by the alien insects. During this process he is given the power to communicate directly with the insects - which will help him ask them for the correct secretions - which will make his family / clan very rich.

Comment: There are some points of contact with *Brightness Falls from the Air* by James Tiptree Jr., but the story doesn't match. But I seem to vaguely remember something similar, I'll have a look in my library.

Comment: It makes me think of "The war for eternity" by Christopher Rowley.... however it's many years since I read it so just guessing